# Помогите разобраться: p = $('.popup__overlay')

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Есть функция

```
p = $('.popup__overlay')
$('#popup__toggle').click(function() {
    p.css('display', 'block')
})
p.click(function(event) {
    e = event || window.event
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(p).css('display', 'none')
    }
})
$('.popup__close').click(function() {
    p.css('display', 'none')
})
```

Вопрос. Что это за строчка? что она делает?

```
p = $('.popup__overlay')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` - это функция из библиотеки [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). В данном конкретном случае она выбирает все элементы на странице с классом `popup__overlay`.

[Документация jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)

[Документация по селекторам](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

[Документация на русском](http://jquery-docs.ru/)